# I am unable to install citus version 10.2 on my ubuntu 21.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, citus, ubuntu-21.04

I am unable to install citus version 10.2 on my ubuntu 21.04
with the following errors :
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-14-citus-10.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'postgresql-14-citus-10.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-14-citus-10.2'
I am trying to install it using the citus documentation
can anyone suggest some solution
This is the command:- sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-14-citus-10.2

Comment: the [installation instructions](https://www.citusdata.com/download/) are pretty clear, follow them

Answer (score 0):

We at Citus do not create packages for Ubuntu distros that are not LTS.

You should have seen the error messages when installing the packaging repositories using the official installation instructions.

Comment: Recreated in 22.04